# Is the Hyperbolic plane a proper space?

Tags: compactness, hyperbolic-geometry

Given the definition of a proper metric space: a metric space is proper if every closed ball is compact. I want to show that the hyperbolic plane in the Poincare disc model is proper, but I don't know how. I tried to use Heine-Borel theorem, but I'm not sure it applies to other spaces other than the Euclidiean space. (We've only saw the disc model and the half upper plane model in class).

Comment: What do you know about the hyperbolic plane?

Comment: I assume you want the metric to be the hyperbolic distance, and not the one inherited as a subset of $\mathbb R^2.$ Both metrics give the same topology, but, in the inherited metric, it is not proper. In the Poincare metric, it is.

Comment: We've studied the two models I noted, and the metrics in each one, including angles, distances and areas. We also sorted the oriantation- preserving isometries (we only saw actions of the form of mobius actions induced from $SL_2(\R)$). The course is called "Geometric Group Theory".

Comment: In the poincare disk model, first show that the closed ball centered at the origin is compact. In general, there is an isometry moving any center of any closed ball to the origin.

Comment: Incidentally: While you are under no obligation to accept answers to your questions, as time progresses, you will find it increasingly difficult to get any answers at MSE if your acceptance rate is zero.